# Using Push Constant to refresh every frame

Tags: vulkan

The code is as follow:

```
# //begin info
# //begin render pass

mypipeline->bind(commandbuffer);

for (auto& obj : gameObjects) {
obj.transform2d.rotation = glm::mod(obj.transform2d.rotation + 0.05f, glm::two_pi<float>());
simplepushconstantdata push{};
push.offset = obj.transform2d.translation;
push.color = obj.color;
push.transform = obj.transform2d.mat2();
vkCmdPushConstants(commandbuffer, mypipelinelayout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT | VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT, 0, sizeof(simplepushconstantdata), &push);
obj.model->bind(commandbuffer);
obj.model->draw(commandbuffer);
    }
# //end render pass 
# //end info
```

In my achievement, I establish 3 commandbuffer, and I find that during the establishment the 3 rotation value was fixed into the command buffer.

so how to change the PushConstant Value in the commandbuffer? Can it be achieved?

Or just I have to regenerate new command buffer(with updated rotation value) in my render loop?

What I exactly want to know is that can I update push constant value in render loop without rebuild command buffer

Comment: "*I find that during the establishment the 3 rotation value was fixed into the command buffer.*" How do you know that the "3 rotation value" is not changing?

Comment: because in my initial achievement, i first create 3 command buffers,and  load all the cmds in it (the push constant included), and in my render loop i just invoke these 3 cmdbuffer.

Comment: and in the render result the triangle is rotating in very small angle, which means that the rotation angle in limit in small range, and i debuged find the push constants value is fixed in the cmdbuffer.
and If I wanna a continue rotate result, I have to create cmdbuffer in every render loop and refresh the push constant in it.

Answer (score 1):

Push constants are part of the command buffer state. That means that if you build a command buffer, the push constant value you set at command buffer creation will be fixed (for that command buffer). So in order to "update" that state you need to recreate the command buffer with the new values.

For your use-case, using a uniform buffer would probably be the better option as that can be updated without having to recreate command buffers.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it really solves my question.